# impl Display for Optional Struct

Tags: rust

How do I implement Display for an optional Enum that I own. Example

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
enum MyKind { new, existing}
```

I have tried

```
impl fmt::Display for Option<MyKind>
```

and get E0117

I have already implemented

```
impl fmt::Display for MyKind
```

and want to be able to call .to_string() on both MyKind and Option<MyKind>

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate
    --> src/lib.rs:7074:1
     |
7074 | impl fmt::Display for Option<DITKind>  
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------
     | |                     |
     | |                     `std::option::Option` is not defined in the current crate
     | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate